# What is the difference between wp-admin>Export>All content and MySql dump and import

Tags: migration, import, export

What is the difference between:

Using the WP-Admin console to do an "All content" export of an existing Wordpress site and similar import on a fresh install of Wordpress on a different server, AND

Using the MySql export with schema and data on the existing site and a MySql import on the site hosting the fresh install of Wordpress?

And the motivation for this question really is, what is the best way to migrate a Wordpress site from an existing host machine to another host machine?  What is the best practice for migrating all the plug-ins and their corresponding configuration?  Assume that the target host and destination host both have the same version of Wordpress installed.

Answer (score 0):

The Export / Import route will export and import your site's **content** -- all pages, posts, any custom posts, images (if you tell it to grab them during the import phase), and any associated metadata for the various posts & pages. (Note that you'll need to make sure any custom post types are set up on the new site *before* you run the import.)

The MySQL dump and import will get **everything** for your entire site, including which plugins are enabled*, what theme is in use*, all the settings, all the users, etc.

### References

- [Importing Content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content)
- [Tools » Export](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen)

### Migration

Also, if you haven't already [Googled `wordpress migration best practice`](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+database+schema), it turns up a number of suggestions:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
- http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-a-wordpress-site-to-a-new-domain-and-hosting/
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/moving-wordpress-site/

...were all on the first page of results for me.

---

* Note that the database export won't *install* the plugins and themes for you; you'd need to make sure you copy the relevant directories and files to the new server.

Comment: There are notable differences here, such as hooks etc firing when you do a WXR import/export which don't happen when you do an SQL transfer, etc

Comment: Yes. I admittedly didn't dive very deep into the topic, and perhaps I should have.